# Informats for dates in SAS

Tags: sas

I am importing a dataset with dates that are in the form MM/DD/YYYY. This is my [edit updated] code

```
DATA AlbumData;
    INFILE '/folders/myfolders/sasuser.v94/NBA60.txt' DLM=','  DSD MISSOVER 
FIRSTOBS=2;
    LENGTH Player $30 Points Date 8
            Team $30 Opponent $30 Results $30;
        INFORMAT Data ANYDTDTE.;
    INPUT Player -- Results;
    FORMAT ReleaseDate MMDDYY10.
RUN;
```

My issue is no matter what I try the date will be blank in the output. How do I go about fixing this?

A few lines of the code

```
Player,Points,Date,Team,Opponent,Results
Wilt Chamberlain,100,3/2/1962,Philadelphia Warriors,New York Knicks,win
Kobe Bryant,81,1/22/2006,Los Angeles Lakers,Toronto Raptors,win
```

This note is under every line in the log

```
 NOTE: Invalid data for Date in line 16 21-28.
```

Comment: Show a couple of lines of the data file. Also any notes/warnings from the SAS log. If the dates are really in MDY order then just use the `mmddyy.` informat.  Also make sure to add a FORMAT statement for the date variable. Otherwise the raw number of days since 1960 will print instead of something that a human can understand.

Comment: Updated. This code is nearly identical to a similar task I was working on, but I can't seem to get it to fit for this data set.

Comment: Is the variable with date values named `date` or `data`? Your `informat` statement is using `data`.

Comment: Wow. Yes that was the issue. Thank you.

Comment: You should have also had a note that the variable `Data` was uninitialized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The informat was not getting assigned because of a typo in the name of the variable.